# firebase - android - RunLoop in 9.0.0

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase 9.0.0 calls back to the listeners on the main thread on Android. I'd like to change this and use my custom executors.

(I've read that in previous firebase versions (2.5.2) there was a [RunLoop](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/RunLoop#public-method-summary) class.

I have not tried that but it seemed to be the entry point to configure custom executors/threads.)

Is it possible to configure the callback executors in 9.0.0 somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your own executors is not yet supported in 9.0.0. We're looking to (re-)add support for it in an upcoming release.

Keep in mind that Firebase Database only surfaces the callback on the main thread. All its network interaction and internals run on a separate thread already.

If you want to do significant work in the callback, for the moment you'll have to use the usual methods (`AsyncTask` or one of its brethren).

Comment: I see. Thank you. Then I I'll start my executor in the callback.